# Android and iOS Facebook invalid access token logout

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to understand the implications of a log out button on a iOS and Android... If I get the long-lived Access Token (60 days) and the user logs out, is the token invalid?. References on facebook documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#expiredtokens

> Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.

Does this mean that if the user logs out, the long-lived token is invalid?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Logout

> On all the platforms it will also invalidate any access token that you have for the user that was issued before the logout.

Does this apply for the long-lived access token or just the short lived?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It invalidates the tokens locally (i.e. on the actual client device or browser), but the token itself is still valid. If you store the access token server side, you can still use it.